# Tapestry5 Form - user-defined html attribute

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I have a problem with tapestry5 t:Form component. I'd like to add my own html tag but do not how. I would like to have something like:

```
<t:form clientValidationEnabled="false" class="formclass" myTag="${tagValue}">
```

and render form should looks like:

```
<form clientvalidationenabled="false" class="formclass" myTag="value">
```

I tried to add theattribute with `t` prefix but does not help. I know it'd be parse as component property (`@Parameter`) but I don't know how to pass it through.

Is there any way how pass the attribute to the generated html element? (without js)

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I answer my question. The solution with prefix works fine. So it should looks like:

```
<t:form clientValidationEnabled="false" class="formclass" t:myTag="${tagValue}">
```

My fault was the value of `getTagValue()` cause it was not set because inner component `@SetupRender` wasn't finished. So the value was empty and empty html tag is not rendered.